# Assign CSS var() to style property value of another CSS element with pure CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-variables, css-calc

Assuming I have an element `#banner` with `font-size: 36px;` as shown in the **Code Snippet** below:

```css
#banner {
    font-size: 36px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  <h1>Hello StackOverflow!!</h1>
</div>
```

---

How can I retrieve that `36px` from `#banner's` css property `font-size` and assign it to a **[css variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables)** so I can use the **[calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)** function to dynamically set the `font-size` of another element, say `#someOtherBanner` to `#banner's` `font-size` value divided by say, 3 thus returning `12px`.

---

A dummy representation of what I'm looking for can be seen in the **Code Snippet** below:

```css
:root {
  --bannerFontSize: #banner.font-size;
}

#banner {
    font-size: 36px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
}
#someOtherBanner {
    font-size: calc(var(--bannerFontSize) / 3); // should return 12px
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  <h1>Hello StackOverflow!!</h1>
</div>
<hr />
<div id="someOtherBanner">
  <h1>Hello from me too, StackOverflow!!</h1>
</div>
```

---

The closest thing I found that might help was the [CSS attr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) function that retrieves an attribute's value from HTML elements (one can use this to set elements' css properties to an attribute while simultaneously setting css variables to the attribute's value) but according to [CanIUse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-attr), it is not compatible with any browser so far.

This would be a piece of cake using JavaScript or css preprocessors like SCSS but what would be the Vanilla CSS approach to do this?

Comment: to start with: if both element don't have any relation of parent/child then there is no way to share some value considering inheritance. Even common CSS variable won't work (unless you consider `:root` or a shared parent element)

Comment: So unless browsers fixes the compatibility issues of the CSS `attr()` function, there is no way to do this?

Comment: Even with attr() I don't see how you can do it with sibling element

Comment: @TemaniAfif Instead of an element interacting directly with it's sibling, it can just use the value that css variable retrieved from the sibling using the `attr()` function.

Comment: in this case simply use an inline CSS variable instead of an attribute (https://jsfiddle.net/vgzuyLkb/). If you are able to set attribute you can set inline style

Comment: I forked the official MDN fiddle to show you what I meant by using `attr()` to retrieve the style: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/ngxhf9vr/

Comment: I understand what you meant, and attr() works with attribute which is something *inline* that you add to the element so why not setting inline CSS using CSS variable that you can easily use (like the fiddle I shared)

Comment: In the hypothetical scenario that one can access the HTML, that would be fine, but I'm talking about situations where we only have access to css and have to make use of just the inline style attribute and nothing else.

Comment: and what I have done? I used the inline style attribute to set a CSS variable like you did to set a background.

Comment: haha so how would you extract css properties from another element property (that were already set) and apply it inline to a nw element using the inline approach lol

Comment: now we get back to my initial comment. This is something you cannot also do with attr() even if they get supported. Something you cannot simply do, that was my first comment about this.

Comment: Oh I understand what you mean now. But in the jsFiddle that I forked from MDN above, how did I get to retrieve the styles from the inline style attribute then? I don't understand that though.

Comment: you simply read it as a string, you can do nothing with it ... but if there was a CSS variable there you can do what you want

Comment: I realised that just now when I tried to use the css property that I extracted in the fiddle. Damn.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you could do is simply use the same CSS variable as *both* the `font-size` in the banner and the `padding` in the secondary banner.

This would look like this:

```css
:root {
  --bannerFontSize: 36px;
}

#banner {
  font-size: var(--bannerFontSize);
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

#someOtherBanner {
  padding: calc(var(--bannerFontSize) / 3);
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  <h1>Hello StackOverflow!!</h1>
</div>
<hr />
<div id="someOtherBanner">
  <h1>Hello from me too, StackOverflow!!</h1>
</div>
```

Note that in your example you have a division by `/ 3px`, whereas you want `/ 3`.

Comment: Corrected the `/ 3px` to `/ 3`. Thanks for the heads up man. And yes, using a common css variable would be the best way to go about this but assuming I have to change the layout of a site with a bunch of elements with the same class names (not id) having their own unique inline `font-style` properties in the HTML, it would be easier if I could retrieve an element's current property value and perform calculations based on the value instead.